# Message after suggested edit is not translated

Tags: bug, status-futuro, tradução, internacionalização

After you suggest an edit, you get this message, which is in English:

[image: Message: This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.]

Can it please be translated to Portuguese?

Comment: Thanks, ProgramFOX. It's great to see contributions from people all around the world.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: Duplicata:  http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2067/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message text is properly configured for our translation system and is awaiting manual translation. As soon as it is translated, it will appear correctly on the website. Sorry for the delay in this process. Alternatively, the moderators could ask Gabe to translate it manually ahead of the process.

Comment: Is it already translated? I still see the English text.